# Auto updating a date in a cell when another cell is edited - Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, updates, cells

I have looked at various scripts etc. on this site which should solve my query but none of them seem to work.

Basically I have a Google Sheet where members can update a figure in column F.  They should also change the edit date in column G but invariably forget that, so I am looking to automate it.

I am a complete novice when it comes to writing scripts etc but, as I have said, none of those I have tried have worked.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You should include code you have tried, and how it did or did not work, along with statements that illustrate how you *think* it should have worked, or what was lacking in what it did. As it is, your "question" is just an open-ended "will somebody do something to help me somehow?", which is not useful at all.

Comment: It's a good question, but you need to show us what have you tried

Comment: I can't remember all of the different versions I have tried but some are below:-

function onEdit(e) {
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var cols = [6]
if (s.getName() !== "Members" || cols.indexOf(e.range.columnStart) == -1) return;
s.getRange(e.range.rowStart, e.range.columnStart + 1)
    .setValue(new Date());
};

Comment: I have also tried this:-

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim A As Range, B As Range, Inte As Range, r As Range
    Set A = Range("F:F")
    Set Inte = Intersect(A, Target)
    If Inte Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each r In Inte
            r.Offset(0, 1).Value = Date
        Next r
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Comment: function myFunction() {
  Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("F:F,X:X"), Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Count < Columns.Count Then
            On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Dim r As Range
            For Each r In Intersect(Target, Range("F:F,X:X"), Range("10:" & Rows.Count))
                With r.Offset(0, 1)
                    .Value = Now   
.NumberFormat = "dd-mmm-yyyy"  
End With
Next r
End If
End If
bm_Safe_Exit:
 Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
}

Comment: With some attempts I am getting error messages, which I cannot remember now, sorry.  With others the script appears to be ok but when i change data in column F the date in G is not affected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this one earlier and it didn't work but I have just tried again and it seems to be doing the job now :)

```
function onEdit(event) {
  var sheetName = 'Members',
  watchCol = 6, 
  stampCol = 7,
  r = event.range;

  if (r.getSheet().getName() !== sheetName
      || r.columnStart !== watchCol
      || r.rowStart < 2)
    return;
  r.getSheet()
      .getRange(r.rowStart, stampCol)
      .setValue(event.value ? new Date() : null);
}
```

Comment: Maybe I haven't found the answer, or have done something else wrong. Whenever I change column F a new date is entered into column G but when others change F then nothing happens to G.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I am still having no joy when other users edit the spreadsheet. As the owner everything works as it should for me but when other users (with edit permissions) enter a figure in to column F the date in G does not get updated. Any ideas please, have I missed something regarding permissions for example?